# Serverless one lambda triggered by multiple s3 buckets

Tags: amazon-s3, serverless-framework

In my Serverless YAML file I defined a lambda function with multiple S3 events from different buckets, already existing, such as below

```
functions:
  my-lambda:
    handler: ...
    name: my-lambda
    description: 'Fetcher'
    environment:
      env_host: aws
    events:
      - s3:
          bucket: bucket1
          existing: true
      - s3:
          bucket: bucket2
          existing: true
```

The command “serverless deploy” fails with below text:

```
Only one S3 Bucket can be configured per function. In “my-lambda" you're attempting to configure "bucket1" and "bucket2" at the same time.
```

Is it possible to configure one lambda with multiple s3 buckets in Serverless?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately no.

From the [Serverless doc](https://www.serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/events/s3#using-existing-buckets):

> IMPORTANT: You can only attach 1 existing S3 bucket per function.

AWS Lambda allows only one Amazon S3 bucket as an event source. You can define `s3` multiple times in `events` with a different event type but it still must be from the same bucket, see [here](https://www.serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/events/s3#triggering-separate-functions-from-the-same-bucket).

You can though use the `handler` you wrote multiple times to define multiple functions like this:

```
functions:
  my-lambda-bucket1:
    handler: ...
    name: my-lambda-bucket1
    description: 'Fetcher with bucket1'
    environment:
      env_host: aws
    events:
      - s3:
          bucket: bucket1
          existing: true
  my-lambda-bucket2:
    handler: ...
    name: my-lambda-bucket2
    description: 'Fetcher with bucket2'
    environment:
      env_host: aws
    events:
      - s3:
          bucket: bucket2
          existing: true
```

Comment: I see, there is a bug in Serverless. Fixed in the same way, splitting events.

Comment: Oh so you can actually note down two different buckets when the events are different?

Comment: Yes, since you are deploying 2 functions with same app